# Where do we save demo app dependencies when buiding a module?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, package.json

I am building my first node module. Inside the module there is a demo application. The demo is only useful during development. Where do we put the demo's dependencies?

The first answer that comes to mind, is to put them into `devDependencies`, because they are only useful during development. That being said, usually I reserve `devDependencies` for build tools not for modules that run the (demo) app.

So the question is, when developing a module that contains its own demo app, where does one put the demo app's dependencies?

- `dependencies`?
- `devDependencies`?
- `someWhereElse`?

This is the module: https://github.com/shaunluttin/aurelia-open-id-connect

Here is a high-level graph of the dependencies in my module. The locations in `()` are based on the answer from Pranesh.

```
demo
  third-party-modules (optionalDependencies)
  my-module
    third-party-modules (dependencies)
```

When someone installs our module, we want them only to pull down `my-module/third-party-modules`. When someone clones our repo, we want them top be able to also pull down `demo/third-party-modules`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, demo apps will be dependent on the module you build, `aurelia-open-id-connect` in your case. If you have any other dependencies for the demo app other than your module, it should come under `optionalDependencies`.

Refer [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#optionaldependencies)

These modules should be installed with `-O` option. Example, `npm i express -O`

Comment: I am having trouble understanding how the demo app will be dependency on the module itself. For instance, here is my module structure: https://github.com/shaunluttin/aurelia-open-id-connect/tree/master/src. The module is inside `src/open-id-connect/` and the demo app is everything else inside `src/`. On publish of the module, the `dist` includes only the contents of `src/open-id-connect`: https://github.com/shaunluttin/aurelia-open-id-connect/tree/master/dist/amd Am I structuring my demo app in an unconventional way?

Comment: Examples won't be the dependencies, they will be **dependent** on the module. Take a look at https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/examples/auth/index.js#L5 .These examples are dependent on the module(express)

Comment: Okay. This makes sense to me, that the demo is not a dependency. That's clear. The demo, though, has its own dependencies, and what I am wondering, is where to store those.

Comment: It should be in `optionalDependencies`. Edited the answer to make it clear.

Comment: Okay. I updated my answer to include my interpretation of your answer. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: It's perfect. Use `.npmignore` to prevent example getting into the published package.